# Writing an ODBC driver or OleDb provider that queries a REST API

Tags: powerbi, odbc, driver, oledb

I want to write a bare bones ODBC driver (maybe an OleDb provider)  that queries a REST API in order to provide data from a legacy app to Power BI.

In order to simplify the creation, the driver is read only and does not need to make any transformation to the request it receives or to the response it sends back. All those transformations are to be made at the REST site. Just pass through the requests, provide the database schema and respond to queries.

Does anyone have any suggestions, please?